# Model with has_secure_password fails create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does anyone know why create fails on simple model with has_secure_password?

I have rails 4.0.2
I have a really simple model:
$ rails g resource provider name password_digest

with models/provider.rb

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_secure_password
end
```

using rails console I am trying to create a model:

```
2.0.0-p353 :013 >   Provider.create(name: "boot", password: "Boot1234tooB")
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
 => #<Provider id: nil, name: "boot", password_digest: "$2a$10$yOkRGwFioJVhZTwiEKTQseGsHM9vQ82UAPAkkF4FGUwX...", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
2.0.0-p353 :014 > print Provider.all.to_yaml
  Provider Load (4.7ms)  SELECT "providers".* FROM "providers"
--- []
 => nil
```

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 2):

You should set `password_confirmation`:

```
Provider.create(name: "boot", password: "Boot1234tooB", password_confirmation: "Boot1234tooB")
```

More about [has_secure_password](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html)